# Instance Variables in Stateless Session Bean - state is maintained how?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, instance-variables, stateless-session-bean

**Server**  running on GlassFish 3.0

```
@Stateless(mappedName="messengerservice")
public class MessengerService implements MsnService{

    int count;


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        count = count+1;
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      MsnService br = (MsnService) ctx.lookup("java:global/EJbTutorial/MessengerService");
      System.out.println(br.getCount());
  }
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

EJB spec says that server maintains a pool of session beans ,  i increment the value in one instance , re look up hopefully get a new instance and it seems the instance variable value is maintained

How is it possible ? unless server keeps returning me the same instance every time, or is it.

I even tried it executing it in a loop and same result.
Can any shed some light

Comment: If you only have one request at a time, then the container only needs to create a single instance of the bean. If you run multiple clients in parallel threads, you should see that there are multiple instances of the bean in play.

Comment: @TomAnderson it certainly did .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test , if Stateless Beans indeed pooled , as Tom Anderson suggested , i tried executing it parallel threads

Client

```
ExecutorService service =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);           

for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
  Future future=  service.submit(new MessengerClient("Thread "+i+" :"));
  }        

service.shutdown();
```

**Output**

```
Thread 0 :1
Thread 1 :1
Thread 3 :1
Thread 4 :1
Thread 2 :1
Thread 1 :2
Thread 2 :3
Thread 3 :4
Thread 4 :5
Thread 0 :6
Thread 1 :7
Thread 2 :8
Thread 3 :9
Thread 4 :10
Thread 0 :11
Thread 1 :2
Thread 2 :12
Thread 3 :13
Thread 4 :14
Thread 2 :15
Thread 1 :16
Thread 3 :17
Thread 4 :18
Thread 0 :19
Thread 0 :20
```

Well this proves that indeed new instances are used by the threads

Answer (score 1):

It gives the correct output, [referred from this link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=841), it says

> With stateless beans, the clients may call any available instance of
>   an instantiated bean for as long as the EJB container has the ability
>   to pool stateless beans. This enables the number of instantiations of
>   a bean to be reduced, thereby reducing required resources.
>
> Bean pooling Any stateless session bean method instance that is not 
>   currently invoked is equally available to be called by an EJB
>   container or application server to service the request of a client. 
>   This allows the EJB container to pool stateless bean instances and
>   increase performance.
>
> Scalability Because stateless session beans are able to service
>   multiple clients, they tend to be more scalable when applications have
>   a large number of clients. When compared to stateful session beans,
>   stateless session beans usually require less instantiation.
>
> Performance An EJB container will never move a stateless session bean
>   from RAM out to a secondary storage, which it may do with a stateful
>   session bean; therefore, stateless session beans may offer greater
>   performance than stateful session beans.

read more about the [difference between stateless and stateful session beans](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=841)...